# Soap UI Deploy as war in weblogic issues

Tags: soapui

I have deployed a Soap UI war project in weblogic. After deploying, for the first request soapUI is dispatching to the right mock response. But after the first request, I get the below error:

```
<27/02/2014 10:33:34 AM EST> <Error> <com.eviware.soapui.mockaswar.MockAsWarServlet> <BEA-000000> <null
com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.DispatchException: Missing operation for soapAction [] and body element [{http://usage.optus.ws.rsc.app.roamware.com}getPolicySpecificUsage] with SOAP Version [SOAP 1.1]
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.soap.SoapUtils.findOperationForRequest(SoapUtils.java:359)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockRunner.dispatchPostRequest(WsdlMockRunner.java:250)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockRunner.dispatchRequest(WsdlMockRunner.java:375)
    at com.eviware.soapui.mockaswar.MockAsWarServlet$MockServletSoapUICore.dispatchRequest(MockAsWarServlet.java:261)
    at com.eviware.soapui.mockaswar.MockAsWarServlet.service(MockAsWarServlet.java:190)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.dms.wls.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:330)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.doIt(WebAppServletContext.java:3684)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3650)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2268)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2174)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1446)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
```

I have used the "SCRIPT" to distatch to the responses and I'm using the groovy script.

Please let me know the resolution for this issue.. Its bit critical for me.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does this mock service work correctly from within soapUI?

Comment: Yes ... it works correctly within SoapUI. But when I deploy it in Weblogic, I get the above error!!

Answer (score 1):

Almost 2 years...

This is a typical library issue. Weblogic uses orawsdl.jar, which has different implementation that caused the operation not be found.

Use https://github.com/eveoh/weblogic-soapui-mock-ear to wrap the war into ear will fix the issue as it resolves most of the known library issues.

Comment: For what WebLogic version does it work? It seems that not for 12.2.1

Comment: My last test was on 12.1.3. I haven't tried it with 12.2.1 yet.